# How to properly format an image url in a Vue.js single-file-component?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, orchardcms

After about a week of tinkering, I have managed to introduce webpack and Vue.js single file components into my existing Orchard (ASP.NET) module.

Now I've unexpectedly hit a snag, and for the life of me, I'm stumped.  I have several image resources that are part of my custom Orchard theme, which is a separate module (*.csproj) within my Orchard solution.

So (at the risk of demonstrating my woefully inadequate understanding of URL concatenation in web projects) I innocently add this line to my Vue.js single file component:

```
<img src="~/Themes/MyOrchardTheme.Theme/Images/AnImage.png">
```

Now when webpack tries to process this and bundle my component I get this error:

```
Can't resolve 'Themes/MyOrchardTheme.Theme/Images/AnImage.png' in 'redacted'    C:\Projects\Orchard\Modules\redacted\Module not found
```

This kind of makes sense, because the layout of my projects and resources locally and the layout after deployment to Azure obviously differ.

So what is the right way to specify the url for my image as it will exist at runtime on the server, without specifically testing for it's existence when transpiling with webpack?

Comment: You probably want to use `file-loader` and in the `loader` param declare where the images are going to be loaded from.

Comment: When you use ~ you are requesting Webpack to look for the file locally in embed it in the bundle (either as a Data-URI or as a static file depending on the size). Simply remove the ~ and use an absolute path which will exist on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to accept this as the answer, in case someone can offer something better, but after some tinkering I was able to solve my problem by using this:

```
<img :src="theimage" />
```

and adding a computed property like this:

```
computed: {
   theimage: function () {
      return '/Themes/MyOrchardTheme.Theme/Images/AnImage.png';
   }
```

This will bypass the *Webpack transpiler* (or *vue-loader* or *whatever*) check to make sure the resource can be located and has the added benefit that I can programmatically control the image displayed, which (although not mentioned) is ultimately what I wanted to do (code not shown).  I was expecting to use **v-if** or **v-show** with multiple image tags, but using a computed property killed two birds with one stone.

Thanks to everyone who provided feedback. - I have a great deal to learn!

Comment: If you just take away the ~ and leave it in the src (so: /Themes/MyOrchardTheme.Theme/Images/AnImage.png) it should work fine. The ~ tells vue loader to treat the asset as a module request. The tilde is used as a shortcut in razor to build absolute paths without having to use @Url.Content